# Reactjs - Method returns result before the API call get the data. ( always empty object )

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

In my simplified code:

```
static getData(Id) {
  const data = [];
  api.getData(lId)
    .then((Res) => {
      data.push(Res);
    });
  return data;
}
```

The API endpoint gets the data but it takes some time. the method always returns [], but if I put a console.log(Res), the data is there. It means the method returns the initial `const data = [];` and it doesn't wait until the API returns the data.

How should I fix this problem?

Regrds

Comment: By using promises correctly. `getData` has to return a promise. See the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with your timing here:

```
static getData(Id) {
  const data = [];
  api.getData(lId)
    .then((Res) => {
      data.push(Res);
    });
  return data;  <-- Gets returned before the promise resolves/rejects
}
```

If you need to do extra processing on your data before it is returned to the caller - in your example, you're putting it into an array - you're going to need to wrap it with another Promise:

```
static getData(Id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      api
        .getData(Id)
        .then((Res) => {
          const data = []
          data.push(Res);
          resolve(data)
        })
        .catch(reject)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise).

For example:

```
static getData(Id) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    api.getData(Id)
      .then((Res) => {
         resolve(Res);
      });
  });
}
```

And use this method like this:

```
getData(15)
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Comment: I used Promise, api is a promise.

Comment: Yes, and you should use another promise because api does the call asynchronous.